# Transform Rows data to column from a grouped data in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading a csv file.

The data is not sorted in any order. I have read the file using the below code

```
List<LatencyData> latencys = new List<LatencyData>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {

            LatencyData latencyData = null;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');
                var row = values[0].Split(',');


                latencyData = new LatencyData
                {
                    TimeStamp = (row[0] + "000"),
                    Prefix = row[1],
                    Uplink = row[2],
                    Latency = row[3]
                };

                latencys.Add(latencyData);
            }
        }
```

The Next step was to group on the basis of Time stamp.

```
var grouped = latencys.GroupBy(item => item.TimeStamp);
```

which looks like this after grouping.

[image]

Now I want to transform the data into this format

```
timeStamp  Latency0 Latency1 Latency2 Latency3 Latency4
1541030400  198      267.67   263      null      198
```

for that i used this part.

```
var transformed = grouped.Select(g => new
        {
            Hubs = g.Select(hub => new
            {
                stamp = g.Key,
                Latency0 = g.Where(item => item.Uplink == "0").Select(data => data.Latency),
                Latency1 = g.Where(item => item.Uplink == "1").Select(data => data.Latency),
                Latency2 = g.Where(item => item.Uplink == "2").Select(data => data.Latency),
                Latency3 = g.Where(item => item.Uplink == "3").Select(data => data.Latency),
                Latency4 = g.Where(item => item.Uplink == "4").Select(data => data.Latency),
            })
        });
```

The Result is not correct and there is many rows for the same values are returned. It should have only one row per key

```
timeStamp  Latency0 Latency1 Latency2 Latency3 Latency4
1541030400  198      267.67   263      null      198
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. However you might want to return a *value* for each latency instead of list of objects:

```
var transformed = grouped.Select(g => new
{
    Hubs = g.Select(hub => new
    {
       stamp = g.Key,
       Latency0 = g.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uplink == "0")?.Latency,
       Latency1 = g.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uplink == "1")?.Latency,
       Latency2 = g.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uplink == "2")?.Latency,
       Latency3 = g.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uplink == "3")?.Latency,
       Latency4 = g.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uplink == "4")?.Latency,
    })
});
```